# What is the efficient way to traverse a list?

Tags: pointers, data-structures, linked-list

What is the difference between traversing link list until `temp!=NULL` (temporary variable use to traverse list) and `temp->next!=NULL`?

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
cout<<temp->data;
temp=temp->next;
}
```

---

```
while(temp->next!=NULL)
{
cout<<tmep->data;
temp=temp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is first one will print all the node's data in a linked list.
But the second one will print all the node's data except the last one's. As the last node's next pointer would point to null, thus the condition inside the while loop would be false and it won't execute for the last node.

Comment: Golam rahman that was the thing i wanted to know...thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The main answer I would give is that the above algorithms can be used equally to traverse a linked list. Here's the difference.

**The first algorithm:**
The pointer moves first. Then, it checks the current node. If it is not equal to null, it outputs the value and advances the pointers to the next node. After the traversal is finished, the pointer points to a null value.

**The second algorithm:**
The pointer checks the next node. If it is not equal to null, it advances the pointers to it and outputs the value. After the traversal is finished, the pointer points to the last node.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the second approach, please make sure that the temp variable is not NULL before starting while loop. If you have no item in your list, you will get an exception when trying to access `temp->next` at first line of while loop.

On the other hand, the first approach does not cause this error even if the temp variable is NULL.